# Generic error for operation Ping

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

When I connect my Nexus 5 to the Android Studio (Preview) 0.4.2 on Windows 7 Pro, I get the following message in logcat repeating indefinitely and clogging the console

```
01-22 11:45:06.608  24707-24724/? E/Exchange﹕ Generic error for operation Ping: status 500, result -10
```

Other messages I see intermittently (none of these will show for emulator)

```
19958-22904/? E/SessionUploader﹕ sessions.log cannot be found
617-16345/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
617-1120/? E/LocSvc_IzatApiV02﹕ W/virtual int izat_core::IzatApiV02::injectLocation(GpsExtLocation):665]: error! inject position failed
617-1120/? E/LocSvc_ApiV02﹕ W/virtual loc_api_adapter_err LocApiV02::injectPosition(double, double, float):492]: error! status = eLOC_CLIENT_FAILURE_INVALID_PARAMETER, inject_pos_ind.status = UNKNOWN
```

Any hints on why and how to fix it? The debugging is enabled and I see the app installed and running

Comment: kill adb process form task manger and try to connect your device again.

Comment: Didn't help. For what it's worse there are other error messages (adding)

Comment: Also the new project I just created fails to run because of class not found exception but that's a different bug

Comment: it might a problem of your device drivers as well. Go to Device Manager from control panel, search for Nexus 5 there tight click on that and uninstall the driver. After that remove your device and connect t again. amd install the drivers.

Comment: Ain't going to do no such thing. It works just dandy on command line and in Eclipse. And it used to work before I updated to the latest build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Generic error for operation Ping" isn't an Android Studio or adb issue; the **Exchange** app is spewing that to logcat. The other messages don't show in emulator because those messages appear to be related to hardware, or perhaps location services that aren't on your emulator instance.

You can use Android Studio's logcat filtering to display only the messages that are relevant to you; it's great for suppressing logspam like this.

Comment: Interesting point. Said that why don't I see it in Eclipse? I never seen it in Eclipse's logcat and I develop every day

Comment: Does your logcat in Eclipse have a filter?

Comment: It does but I know how to look at the whole thing. BTW all my problems are seems to be gone with the newest build 0.4.3